# Conditionally restart a service

Tags: ruby, service, conditional-statements, chef-infra, restart

I've just learned how to use notifications and subscriptions in Chef to carry out actions such as restarting services if a config file is changed.

I am still learning chef so may just have not got to this section yet but I'd like to know how to  do the actions conditionally.

Eg1 if I change a config file for my stand alone apache server I only want to restart the service if we are outside core business hours ie the current local time is between 6pm and 6am.  If we are in core business hours I want the restart to happen but at a later time, outside core hours.

Eg2 if I change a config file for my load balanced apache server cluster I only want restart the service if a) the load balancer service status is "running" and b) all other nodes in the cluster have their apache service status as running ie I'm not taking down more than one node in the cluster at once.

I imagine we might need to put the action in a ruby block that either loops until the conditions are met or sets a flag or creates a scheduled task to execute later but I have no idea what to look for to learn how best to do this.

Comment: In both examples you want to always bounce the server when the template is updated.  Then you can use not_if/only_if conditionals on the template resource to control when you allow the template to be modified.  You can't update the template and defer the notification to the service to some time hours later.  You will drop the events and your system will get out of sync.  You're better off front-loaded the timing decision.  For #2 chef is also not designed to be an orchestration agent and that code should not be in a chef recipe.

Comment: You could write an external script for #2 that managed orchestration and fired it with chef, so that the recipe is making the "request" via the external script to bounce the service, subject to the conditions.  Note that electing which service bounces first requires some kind of distributed locking / cluster management mechanism.  Otherwise all members can fire the script at the same time, all check that everyone else is up, then all decided to bounce their service at the same time.  Chef-the-company has a cluster manager, but it is in habitat, not chef-client.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this topic is kind of philosophical. For me, Chef should not have a specific state or logic beyond the current node and run. If I want to restart at a specific time, I would create a cron job with a conditional and just set the conditional with chef (Something like debian's `/var/run/reboot-required`). Then crond would trigger the reboot.

For your second example, the LB should have no issues to deal with a restarting apache backend and failover to another backend. Given that Chef runs regulary with something called "splay" the probability is very low that no backend is reachable. Even with only 2 backends. That said, reloading may be the better way.